# Implementing your own *ngIf

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-ng-if, elementref

I want to create my own *ngIf Directive. The directive will get a number and it wont render the template if the screen inner-Width pixels is less then the number it got.

How can I implement my own *ngIf?

Comment: Try this with css `@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){`

Comment: Please make your question more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called structural directive.

You can check the [source of `*ngIf`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.x/packages/common/src/directives/ng_if.ts#L102)

There is also a section in the Angular docs about that https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives

The main part is

```
 this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
```

which allows to stamp a template.

If you have

```
<my-component *myIf="isTrueOrFalse"></my-component>
```

the `*` will result in

```
<my-component></my-component>
```

being passed as template to the directive, which can then be stamped/removed.

Answer (score -1):

It is pretty straightforward.

Use the good old `ngIf`, like this `*ngIf='someVariable'` and then just toggle this `someVariable` from `true` to `false` when you want it to get rendered or not.

What I would do, is to create an event listener within the component that listens to window width event and looking at the width would decide whether to hide some element or not by setting `someVariable`